# Помогите правильно расставить знаки препинания в просьбе

Tags: пунктуация

Не сильно понимаю как правильно расставить знаки препинания, поставил по интуиции, но правил вообще не знаю. Буду рад за помощь, спасибо.

"Есть просьба: если будет время и возможность, сможешь купить две чёрные ручки?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Со знаками порядок, но имеется смысловая ошибка. В предложении не просьба, а вопрос. Просьба: "Купи, пожалуйста, две чёрные ручки". Вопрос: "Сможешь купить две чёрные ручки?"